# Notification Message Event | Anguilla

Tags: cme, gui-extensions, 2013-sp1-hr1

I am looking to catch the Event, when notification bar shows a notification message in GUI using Anguilla framework.

Actually at that perticular event, I want to catch the messages of certain type using `message.properties.className` and prevent it from displaying in notification bar.

Please suggest the possible options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to add an event listener onto the MessageCenter listening for the "newmessage" event.  You'll probably have to filter off of the returned event object's `data` property.  It's a multi step process, as the `data` object only contains a `messageID` property.  You can use this identifier to retrieve the actual message object, and perform your predicate off of that.

```
$messages.addEventListener('newmessage', function (event) {
    var messageId = event.data.messageID;
    var message = $messages.getMessageByID(messageId);
    var className = message.getClassName();

    if (className === "goal") {
        // do something with goals... etc...
    }
});
```

Hope that helps!

**Update**

If trying to prevent a message of a certain type from displaying completely, I wasn't able to find an out of the box way (at least poking at the 2013 SP1 API, not sure if Web 8 introduced a way).  Calling `doArchive` and `dispose` from the event handler causes the message to show for a brief moment before fading away.

We can of course do a little monkey patching by keeping a reference of the original MessageCenter's `registerMessage` method and overriding it to perform our check in there.  If its a message we should hide, we can call the `doArchive` or `dispose` from there as well as not call the original method.  If the message is fine to show, we then pass the message param to our original method.  Here's a quick example of doing such a process to not display any goal messages:

```
var originalRegisterMessage = Tridion.MessageCenter.prototype.registerMessage; // we store the original register message here...

Tridion.MessageCenter.prototype.registerMessage = function (msg) {
    if (msg.getClassName() === 'goal') {
        // don't do anything if its a goal message
        msg.doArchive(); // marks as read, call this if you still want it to display in the Show All area
        msg.dispose(); // or call this so doesn't show up in notification center at all
        return;
    }
    originalRegisterMessage.call(this, msg); // call the original function if the notification should show
};
```

Comment: SDL Web Cloud added a notification framework/API earlier in 2016, which will also be available in the next on-premise release for SDL Web, planned for Q4 2016. See [SDL Docs for details](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Cloud-v1/GUID-0282D1DD-748A-49F1-B231-DB8DC89B6AC9).

Comment: It works like a charm Alex, Thanks. One point to mention, the lines in code `msg.doArchive(); msg.dispose();` could be removed because these adds no value, if someone just want to hide the notification of certain type, Also I noticed for 'workflownotification' these lines cause a issue because that message(we dispode) is needed in further processing and JS doesn't find it and throws an error.

Comment: @Alex: Overriding `registerMessage` method dosn't work on workflow activities page (which is a "feature Page" view). Though it works as expected on "Dashboard" view.